# Cannot include Android Library dependency from another Android Library using Gradle

Tags: android, dependencies, gradle, android-library

I'm trying to reference ActionBarSherlock from another Android Library in my project. I'm getting this error:

```
package com.actionbarsherlock.app does not exist
```

Here's my project structure

```
MyApplication
|---app
\---libraries
    |---ActionBarSherlock
    |---AndroidCommon
    \---AndroidUtils
```

And here's my **settings.gradle**

```
// App
include ':app'

// Libraries
include ':libraries:ActionBarSherlock:actionbarsherlock'
include ':libraries:AndroidCommon'
include ':libraries:AndroidUtils'
```

Here's the **build.gradle** for ABS

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4.2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion '17.0.0'

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }
}
```

And the **build.gradle** for AndroidCommon

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4.2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0'
    compile project(':libraries:ActionBarSherlock:actionbarsherlock')
    compile project(':libraries:AndroidUtils')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion '17.0.0'
}
```

Is this setup not supported, or am I doing something wrong? ActionBarSherlock and AndroidUtils build just fine with Gradle. It's only when I try to reference those from AndroidCommon that it fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that classes.jar is not being built/packaged for ABS, but the resources are building just fine. Also, everything in AndroidUtils builds fine, including classes.jar.

The build succeeds after manually copying classes.jar into the exploded bundles directory. For some reason Gradle isn't copying this file.

**Update:**

Somehow, nuking the project and re-cloning the repo fixed the gradle builds.